# Node.JS Steam Bot Authentication Error

Tags: node.js, bots, steam

I keep getting this error when ever I start Steam Bot.

```
[2016-05-03 03:00:03.184] [DEBUG] [default] - [Error: SteamGuardMobile]
Error: SteamGuardMobile
at SteamCommunity.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\BOTNEW\node_mo
dules\steamcommunity\index.js:128:14)
at Request._callback (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\BOTNEW\node_modules\ste
amcommunity\components\http.js:62:14)
at Request.self.callback (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\BOTNEW\node_modules
\request\request.js:200:22)
at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
at Request.emit (events.js:172:7)
at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\BOTNEW\node_modules\r
equest\request.js:1067:10)
at emitOne (events.js:82:20)
at Request.emit (events.js:169:7)
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\BOTNEW\node_m
odules\request\request.js:988:12)
at emitNone (events.js:72:20)
```

bot.js http://pastebin.com/07uXJgdJ

bot_manager.js http://pastebin.com/RfJbkrQe

Any help would be amazing and if you are looking for anymore information to help me solve this issue just ask, But I am pretty new to Steam Bot's!

Comment: Check out this issue: https://github.com/DoctorMcKay/node-steamcommunity/issues/34

Comment: I check through it and it does not really make sense to me also my bot only logs in once.

Comment: I need to see the code to understand where the problem is.

Comment: have you got twitter or skype?

Comment: paste it here if you want stackoverflow community to help you.

Comment: I added both the JS files in the post in pastebins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot log into your account, hence the "**Error: SteamGuardMobile**".

You need to use [Steam-TOTP](https://github.com/DoctorMcKay/node-steam-totp) to generate the Two-Factor Auth code for logging in.
To login, you need **shared_secret** which you get when you register a two-factor device.

[This Steam-Community package](https://github.com/DoctorMcKay/node-steamcommunity) has enableTwoFactor which will give you a response object that includes **shared_secret** (Used to login) and **identity_secret** (Used for trade confirmation).

Save these and use Steam-TOTP to generate your 5-digit code used to login via steam mobile authenticator.

```
var code = SteamTOTP.generateAuthCode(shared_secret); // will return 5-digit code
```